can hooks be called inside the nested functions?
In this react component how come usestate is working inside a regular function regfunc? It should throw some kind of error but it isn't.
import { useState } from "react";

export function App() {
  let regfunc = () => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState("hellojo");
  };
regfunc();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}


No, hooks need to be declared at the top-level inside a component. Make b a sub component. What is the goal of this?

Does calling usestate inside a nested function considered as top level? - if it's called while rendering than yes

@Konrad is absolutely correct, but don't do it anyway. It's not idiomatic and confusing and much more likely to accidentally lead to incorrect usage in the future (i.e. calling the function that contains the hook not during render). You should definitely do it if you absolutely have to, but I can't think of a single time when anybody whould ever have to use a hook this way.

It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve here. How are you setting the state? Are you trying to do theming? You'd probably want a custom hook for that.

No, it's literally one of the Rules of Hooks. Your code doesn't throw the error because your code isn't calling the React hook because your code isn't calling regfunc.


Can hooks be called inside the nested functions?

No, from the rules-of-hooks:

Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, nested functions, or try/catch/finally blocks. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns. You can only call Hooks while React is rendering a function component:

✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a function component.
✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a custom Hook.



So it's better to make the Color a custom component like so:


const { useState } = React;

const Color = () => {
    const [color, setColor] = useState("hellojo");
    return color;
};

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
            <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
            <Color />
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>




Hooks need to be declared at the top-level of a component declaration, but they can also be used inside of other hooks. They always have to be at the top-level inside of a function.
Custom hooks
Here is your component slightly rewritten.

I moved a outside of the App component
I renamed it to useColor (hooks should start with "use")

The hook returns a string that can be rendered inside of App.
import { useState } from "react";

let useColor = () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [color, setColor] = useState("hellojo");
  return color;
};

export function App() {
  const b = useColor();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {b}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}



const { useState } = React;

let useColor = () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [color, setColor] = useState("hellojo");
  return color;
};

function App() {
  const color = useColor();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {color}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



Function components
The proper way to declare a component in React is to give it a PascalCase name and return some JSX.
The proper way to do this would be to declare the ColorComponent outside of the app. You can memoize it to optimize performance and avoid unnecessary re-renders based on prop changes.
// App.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ColorComponent = () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [color, setColor] = useState("hellojo");
  return color;
};

const MemoizedColorComponent = React.memo(ColorComponent);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MemoizedColorComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;



const { useState } = React;

const ColorComponent = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("hellojo");
  return color;
};

const MemoizedColorComponent = React.memo(ColorComponent);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MemoizedColorComponent />
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



Or move the component to its own file:
// ColorComponent.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ColorComponent = () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const [color, setColor] = useState("hellojo");

  return color;
};

export default ColorComponent;

And importing it into your App.jsx.

Summary
As mentioned by others, as long as you adhere to the rules of Hooks in React, your function will be either treated as a custom hook or a function component.

Rules of Hooks
Hooks are defined using JavaScript functions, but they represent a special type of reusable UI logic with restrictions on where they can be called.
Only call Hooks at the top level
Functions whose names start with use are called Hooks in React.
Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, nested functions, or try/catch/finally blocks. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns. You can only call Hooks while React is rendering a function component:

✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a function component.
✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a custom Hook.

function Counter() {
  // ✅ Good: top-level in a function component
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  // ...
}

function useWindowWidth() {
  // ✅ Good: top-level in a custom Hook
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  // ...
}

It’s not supported to call Hooks (functions starting with use) in any other cases, for example:

 Do not call Hooks inside conditions or loops.
 Do not call Hooks after a conditional return statement.
 Do not call Hooks in event handlers.
 Do not call Hooks in class components.
 Do not call Hooks inside functions passed to useMemo, useReducer, or useEffect.
 Do not call Hooks inside try/catch/finally blocks.

If you break these rules, you might see this error.
function Bad({ cond }) {
  if (cond) {
    //  Bad: inside a condition (to fix, move it outside!)
    const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  }
  // ...
}

function Bad() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //  Bad: inside a loop (to fix, move it outside!)
    const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  }
  // ...
}

function Bad({ cond }) {
  if (cond) {
    return;
  }
  //  Bad: after a conditional return (to fix, move it before > the return!)
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  // ...
}

function Bad() {
  function handleClick() {
    //  Bad: inside an event handler (to fix, move it outside!)
    const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  }
  // ...
}

function Bad() {
  const style = useMemo(() => {
    //  Bad: inside useMemo (to fix, move it outside!)
    const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
    return createStyle(theme);
  });
  // ...
}

class Bad extends React.Component {
  render() {
    //  Bad: inside a class component (to fix, write a function > component instead of a class!)
    useEffect(() => {})
    // ...
  }
}

function Bad() {
  try {
    //  Bad: inside try/catch/finally block (to fix, move it > outside!)
    const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  } catch {
    const [x, setX] = useState(1);
  }
}



Declaring a component like that will result in remounting it every time the parent changes

@UjjawalBindal a function component is a special function. All function components are functions, but not all functions are function components. There is a difference.

@Konrad my original intent was to show the minimal amount of modifications to convert a into a component and have b be a rendering of said component. I have updated the App component to use a memoized version of the component for better rendering.

@UjjawalBindal Function components replace class components, which are actual JS classes. In React, a function component is a special type of function that returns React elements and can use React features like hooks and props to manage state and render UI. A regular function, on the other hand, is a general-purpose JavaScript function that can perform any operation but is not specifically designed for rendering UI in React. Function components are used to build the UI in a React application, while regular functions can be used for various tasks within or outside of React components.

@Mr.Polywhirl but usestate is working inside a regular function in my example above

@UjjawalBindal I need more coffee. I updated the response to break it out into two sections.

@Mr.Polywhirl why can we use hooks inside custom hooks when hooks needed to be at top level of the function?your answer still doent answer why usestate is working inside a regular function in my example above

@UjjawalBindal Your a variable declares a hook function. Since you called a hook inside of it, it is now a hook. It is not a plain function. React treats it as a hook, not a plain function. If you returned JSX then React would think it was a component definition.

@UjjawalBindal just because you can doesn't mean you should. The fact that you can do something in JavaScript doesn't necessarily mean it's advisable. The language offers a lot of flexibility, and as long as you adhere to the framework's conventions, things should function as expected. However, if you begin implementing logic that deviates from these conventions, you'll be responsible for any resulting issues.
